# Where is GPLv2 located in Ubuntu?

Tags: gpl, gpl-2

Where can I find the GPLv2 license text in Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu is a Debian-based Linux distribution. Packages install their licensing information into the file `/usr/share/doc/<package>/copyright`.

However, the full text of some common licenses is installed into the `/usr/share/common-licenses` directory. This includes the various GPL variants. These files are provided by the `base-files` package.

<sub>This part of Ubuntu/Debian should be extremely stable across versions, but I only checked for Ubuntu 20.04 and Debian Buster.</sub>